# Reduce line of code and best way of using optional

Tags: java

```
    optional(customerVO.getGender()).ifPresent(customer -> {
        if (!customer.equals("-1")) {
            mstCustomer.setGender(customer);
        }
    });

    public static Optional<String> optional(String value) {
        return StringUtils.isNotBlank(value) ? Optional.of(value) : Optional.empty();
    }
```

Above code is working fine. Only thing is that how can I reduce the above code in single line. Is it possible using JDK 1.8?

Please suggest

Answer (score 3):

First case may not be too clean with only lambda:

```
Predicate<String> notMinusOne = Predicate.isEqual("-1").negate();
Optional.ofNullable(customerVO.getGender())
        .filter(notMinusOne)
        .ifPresent(mstCustomer::setGender);
```

In second case you can use filter:

```
public static Optional<String> optional(String value) {
   return  Optional.ofNullable(value).filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank);
}
```

And a merged result:

```
Predicate<String> notMinusOne = Predicate.isEqual("-1").negate();
Optional.ofNullable(customerVO.getGender())
        .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
        .filter(notMinusOne)
        .ifPresent(mstCustomer::setGender);
```

The major benefit of this solution would be having one static method less, thus making it easy for garbage collecting.

Comment: @user7 I was formatting the merged answer. But thank you for reminding:)

Comment: What about the performance. Is it down the performance or it will faster then the original one?

Comment: Should be similar, but if we want to be more efficien we could extract notMinusOne  filter to a static variable, and not create it every time.